# Laravel 5.8 Custom Route for Show Method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I would like to remove a path from a url to customize my route.  I have a City controller with Index and Show methods. Basically, I want to have links to the cities on the home page and I don't want /cities/ in my path.

Note: I am using [Laravel Nova](https://nova.laravel.com/) as my dashboard. And customizing my route below works, but it interferes with my /nova route and I get a 404.

**I would like to turn**

```
Route::get('/cities', 'CityController@index');
Route::get('/cities/{city}', 'CityController@show');
```

**Into This**

```
Route::get('/cities', 'CityController@index');
Route::get('/{city}', 'CityController@show');
```

**CityController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $cities = City::all();

    return view('cities', compact('cities'));
}

public function show(City $city)
{
    return view('cities/city', compact('city'));
}
```

Comment: What if the parameter `{city}` is same as URI string of some other route?

Comment: Laravel Nova shouldn't be affected by this given the fact that it only interacts with models. What is the error thrown by Nova?

Comment: @AdityaThakur I already removed all other routes to test.  The route works, I only get the 404 when I try and go to my /nova route.

Comment: If the route to /nova gets added after the {city} wildcard it might be ignored (I'm not sure how "Laravel Nova" is handling routes). I had a similar problem a while ago.. Route validation might help as well: Route::get('/{city}', 'CityController@show')->when('city', '!=", 'cities')->where(['city' => '[a-z]+']);